# Display image on top of another one in gmail e-mail message

Tags: css, image, gmail

I'm trying to code a a mailing to my clients and i thought that i can insert a gif countdown clock (only the numbers) on top of an another image (i know i can do a gif with a custom background, but the message is too heavy then). Every e-mail client (web or desktop) respects the display:block and margins apart from GMAIL. It displays images one after another.

Is there a way to solve it?  Pls help

Comment: Please share the code you have wrote and a screenshot of how it looks right now.

Comment: Without your code is difficult but remember you have to create the email in old table aligning system so you can put your img in different td to aligning vertical, and every email client support css in different way. For gmail reference: https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1

Comment: I have added the table code. Gmail simply doesent respect minus margins

Answer (score 0):

The table code looks something like that:

```
    <table align="center" width="652" bgcolor="#f5f5f5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background:#f5f5f5; border:none; margin-top: -95px;">
<tr width="650" height="95" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="">
    <td width="134" height="95" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-left: 1px solid #afafaf;"colspan="3">
        <a href="link" border="0" style="border:none;">
            <img src="3.jpg" border="0" width="134" height="95" style="width:134px; height:95px; border:none; display:block;" alt="alt">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td width="381" height="95" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style=""colspan="3" bgcolor="#000">
        <a href="link" border="0" style="border:none;">
            <img src="4.jpg" border="0" width="381" height="95" style="width:381px; height:95px; border:none; display:block;" alt="">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td width="135" height="95" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-right: 1px solid #afafaf;"colspan="3">
        <a href="link" border="0" style="border:none;">
            <img src="5.jpg" border="0" width="135" height="95" style="width:135px; height:95px; border:none; display:block;" alt="alt">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And Gmail displays one image under another, and doesent respect minus margins.

It looks like this right now:

[It looks like this right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEMz2.png)